# How to integrate autodesk forge in SAP Web IDE application?

Tags: sapui5, autodesk-forge, sap-web-ide

i want replace this example of autodesk-forge on sap web ide UI5application
i want integrate autodesk forge viever with the web app create with sap web ide.
the web app start and show the index.html that autorize user to upload model in the viewer.js of autodek forge.
this is the example of simple and little web-application make with autodeks forge.

https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/understand-code

you can see this is very simple application in javascript and node.js that is composed of only 4 file .
Recap: These are the 4 files that are essential for our app to work.

how to integrate in sap web ide application ui5?i can ?

thank for the answer.

Comment: the file of javascript and node.js atuodeskforge vieweer are this:
    1start.js
    2www/index.html
    3www/upload.html
    4www/viewer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the Viewer library by itself is 100% HTML(5)/JavaScript so it's possible to integrate its components with a SAPUI5 project by building a custom UI5 control for Viewer - see [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-ui5-control/) for a tutorial on this topic.

As I am not an expert on SAP techs (and not unsure if their staff answers questions on SO) you may have better luck contacting their support [here](https://support.sap.com/en/index.html) and [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAPUI5/External/en-US) if you got further questions about SAPUI5.